# hello analytics connect timeout

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I have followed this tutorial [Hello Analytics Reporting API V4; Java quickstart for service](http://accountshttps://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java). I am trying to retrieve data from Google Analytics using the Reporting API V4

When running my class HelloAnalytics.java, I get a connection error :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.eai.ga.HelloAnalytics.getReport(HelloAnalytics.java:113)
    at com.eai.ga.HelloAnalytics.main(HelloAnalytics.java:44)
```

I would be very grateful for pointing me into solving the problem.
Thanks for advance !

Comment: Are you sure you followed that tutorial correctly? I find it weird that it mentions Oauth2 yet that is the tutorial for service accounts.   However my java knowledge is limited.  Sounds like its having issues connecting to Googles servers are you behind a fire wall or something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get to the view ID in https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#management from the same machine you execute your java from?